# How to add Method Response in serverless.yml

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, serverless-framework

I'm trying to add CORS header to Method Response header with serverless. Here's my config:

```
  - http:
      path: /myapi
      method: GET
      cors: true
```

My expectation is that CORS is enabled in GET method, but only OPTION method comes up. From my research, I stumbled upon this setting:

```
  - http:
      path: /myapi
      method: GET
      cors: true
      "responseModels": {"application/json": "Empty"}
      "statusCode": "200"
      "responseParameters": {"method.response.header.Access-Control-Allow-Origin": true}
```

However nothing showed up and no error when I deployed serverless. My understanding is that a 200 response status code has to exist before CORS can be added here. When I create a new resource using UI console, a 200 status code is added automatically but serverless doesn't create it.

Any suggestion to achieve this without me creating a 200 status code manually?

Answer (score 0):

This should work. I do this every day. I use Python, I set the CORS to `true` in `serverless.yml` and also must explicitly, manually, set the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` to `*` in every response. Maybe that is not ideal, but it works for us.